# How to subtract next row from first one for each account id in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, row-number, datepart

The question I am trying to answer is how can I return the correct order and sequence of weeks for each ID? For example, while it is true the first week for each ID will always start at 1 (its the first week in the series), it could be the following date in the series may also be within the first week (e.g., so should return 1 again) or perhaps be a date that falls in the 3rd week (e.g., so should return 3).

The code I've written so far is:

```
select distinct 
row_number() over (partition by ID group by date) row_nums
,ID
,date 
from table_a
```

Which simply returns the running tally of dates by ID, and doesn't take into account what week number that date falls in.

[image]

But what I'm looking for is this:

[image]

Here's some setup code to assist:

```
CREATE TABLE random_table

  (
  ID VarChar(50),
date DATETIME
 );

 INSERT INTO random_table
 VALUES
  ('AAA',5/14/2021),
('AAA',6/2/2021),
('AAA',7/9/2021),
('BBB', 5/25/2021),
('CCC', 12/2/2020),
('CCC',12/6/2020),
('CCC',12/10/2020),
('CCC',12/14/2020),
('CCC',12/18/2020),
('CCC',12/22/2020),
('CCC',12/26/2020),
('CCC',12/30/2020),
('CCC',1/3/2021),
('DDD',1/7/2021),
('DDD',1/11/2021)
```

Comment: If you format your code so that it is easily read, that will encourage others to help. And the use of images to provide needed information is highly discouraged as it cannot be readily consumed by others that want to help. I have to ask why this conversion `cast(date as datetime)`? And lastly, your code is syntactically incorrect and will generate an error. The inner most derived table (alias p) has no FROM clause. The name "pivot_table" has on definition either. My guess is that you have overly complicated the code - impossible to suggest a better approach.

Comment: Reformatted. Fixed logic - forget the "pivot_table." I'll leave the picture for now since just to aid the explanation. Cast(date as datetime) was just some formatting I had to do because it was in datetime2(7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with adj as (
    select *, dateadd(day, -1, "date") as adj_dt
    from table_a
)
select
    datediff(week,
        min(adj_dt) over (partition by id),
        adj_dt) + 1 as week_logic,
    id, "date"
from adj
```

This assumes that your idea of weeks corresponds with `@@datefirst` set as Sunday. For a Sunday to Saturday definition you would find 12/06/2020 and 12/10/2020 in the same week, so presumably you want something like a Monday start instead (which also seems to line up with the numbering for 12/02/2020, 12/14/2020 and 12/18/2020.) I'm compensating by sliding backward a day in the weeks calculation. That step could be handled inline without a CTE but perhaps it illustrates the approach more clearly.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, and for pointing out the Sunday assumption, which is ultimately fine for this case. As such, just the second part of your select statement runs just fine on its own. But great trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your objective isn't clear but I think you would benefit from a Tally-Table of the weeks and then LEFT JOIN to your source data.
This will give you a row for each week AND source data if it exists

Comment: Interesting. I never considered that. Query probably more efficient this way as well. Though in this case, not sure how the tallies would reset for each ID. Especially since one ID could start at say 2020-01-01 and another at 2021-05-03. Both should start their tallies at these dates as “week 1.” An example might be helpful if you have it.

Comment: I would create the tally table for all time (define you possible start and end extents) and give each a weeknuber (1 - 1548). I would find the MIN tally.weeknumber for the ID and keep that as a base (do it with the postgress equivalent of a CTE for testability and readability).  I would then take the full data set, join it to the tally table to get the week number and to the CTE to get the base week and subtract the base week from the Tally Week to get the correct week sequence for the ID record.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
   CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [date])=1 THEN 1 
        ELSE DATEPART(WK, (DATE) ) - DATEPART(WK, FIRST_VALUE([DATE]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [date])) END  PD,
   ID,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [date],120)
FROM random_table rt 
ORDER BY ID,[date]
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a0238256d25172985b068f6fe973f35a)

output:

| PD | ID | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 2021-05-14 |
| 3 | AAA | 2021-06-02 |
| 8 | AAA | 2021-07-09 |
| 1 | BBB | 2021-05-25 |
| 1 | CCC | 2020-12-02 |
| 1 | CCC | 2020-12-06 |
| 1 | CCC | 2020-12-10 |
| 2 | CCC | 2020-12-14 |
| 2 | CCC | 2020-12-18 |
| 3 | CCC | 2020-12-22 |
| 3 | CCC | 2020-12-26 |
| 4 | CCC | 2020-12-30 |
| -47 | CCC | 2021-01-03 |
| 1 | DDD | 2021-01-07 |
| 1 | DDD | 2021-01-11 |

- Dates are in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.
- I will leave the `-47` in here, so you can fix it yourself (as an exercise)

Comment: Two dates, eight days apart, but numbered the same...